# Grammar help (Theory of Automata)?

Tags: automaton

Hi guys I have an question, Simple question with Automaton, I am not sure whether this is the right place or not of psoting this kind of question.
Actually this year I have an course Compiler Construction and if anybody knows some good resource it would be good to post here.

At first I have a very basic question: for ex I have an expression like: 2+3*5 , how to write a grammar for this expression? I mean one ambiguous and one non ambiguous example
Thanks

Comment: Actually I am not sure whether i was clear on the question?

Comment: It's kind of hard to develop a grammar given only a single example...

Comment: I mean how to make the parser to start from the * not from the + operator as we know that * has higher priority so what is the grammar should be written for this case to make the parser to start calculating from *, and as I know ANTLR uses top down parsing so can u please give me an grammar for this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "write a grammar for [an] expression". Grammars are rules for production. A simple example is:

```
S -> (S)
S -> SS
S -> [empty]
```

Can you see what this grammar does?

Essentially, this allows you to generate strings like "", "()", "((()())())". Note I said "generate" - logically, you start with a single "S", and work up from there, replacing each S with some "production" on the right. But the key is that any string you generate by this method is "grammatically correct", in a formal sense.

Parsing is the reverse of this - turning a string into the corresponding order of productions. A grammar is ambiguous if this can be done in more than one way.

When you're writing a compiler, first you need to "lex" the input. 2+3*5 should be lexed into something like NUM ADD NUM TIMES NUM (each one is a token). Then you parse the tokens based on a grammar to build a "syntax tree", perhaps something like:

```
  _ + _
2        *
      3/   \5
```

You'll need to write the rules for production such that valid strings are the only things that can be generated. It's a little tricky, and a bit of an art, so I can't help much without more details.

Precedence is handled with different nonterminals (S and T, for example). A real parser will have dozens of them. C has hundreds. By skillfully arranging them, you force certain things to be matched ahead of others.